How much do ebikes actually benefit from ebike specific wheels, tires, and forks?
While it's clear to me how ebikes benefit from more durable drivetrains due to the greater torque they experience, it's less clear for other components.
One aspect I see mentioned online is that because ebikes are heavier, everything must be more durable. Yet ebikes weigh 10-40 lbs heavier than non-electric bikes, much less than human weight variation of 100-200 lbs between the lightest and heaviest riders. This makes me skeptical that weight plays a major role.

Well, on average the e-bike weighs more -- but its rider, too! ;-)

You didn't ask about chains, but here's a question that some people may be interested in. Basically, there may be a case for something like Shimano's LinkGlide chains, which they say are more durable than the regular ones.

Back in the day, I had a high-end 750W mid-drive ebike (meaning the motor's power going through the chain) strip the splines in the rear hub on several (several!) very high-end Crank Brothers wheelsets. The engineering requirements do vary depending on how much power is being conveyed.

There could be other reasons than the technical ones, marketing could be also one.
I would however suspect that certification is the most important. For example, in Europe, fast e-bikes have different/higher certifications requirements than other (e-)bikes, and only certified parts can be installed on them - which is important for professionals, as they expose themselves to liability risks if they don't follow these rules. In Germany, there are also certification requirements for "slow" e-bikes, and online shops have disclaimers on some products about that, even if one orders from another country. In this context, not certifying components excludes the use of these components on e-bikes, and considering the market share of e-bikes now, it represents a significant opportunity loss for component manufacturers.
A point that is however not clear to me is how the different certifications interfere: manufacturers would generally stick to the highest level of ratings (if economically feasible): Europe has E-25 and E-50 (where E-25 is for e-bikes with assistance limited to 25km/h), but North America, 'slow' ebikes are limited to 20mph, so I would not exclude that some manufacturers rate their products for E-50,
because E-25 may not be sufficient for North American markets.
But it's hard to give a general answer. Weight can be a good reason, especially on the high-end, as higher-end components on non e-bikes tend to favour weight over durability. The presence of a motor changes the compromise, making additional weight/rolling resistance less noticeable.
There could be different technical requirements, but it's more linked to the market segmentation than "e-bike"/"non-ebike". E-bikes have created also created new segments, attracting other kind of riders, often less experienced. For example, trekking e-bikes are very popular in Europe for commuting or light touring (so with an additional load). For the upper versions, a differentiator would be lighter wheels, and these bikes use MTB standards. To take a caricatural example, there's a gap for manufacturers if the choice is either go XC race wheels that are super light, but these are designed for 70kg racers with no additional load, or downhill wheels, that are designed to withstand high drops and are probably overbuilt for a touring use. But what you want for a high-end touring e-bike are lightweight, resistant, but also comfortable wheels and drops above 15cm are also not expected, so none of these archetypal MTB wheels will work. So you create a new wheel, that you have to certify for e-bike use, as it's intended for touring e-bikes.
Another example of different compromise, from Bicycle Rolling Resistance: they reviewed the E-50 (fast ebike) version of the GP5000, that has a compound that is more grippy on wet, but has a slightly higher rolling resistance. That makes senses because below 45km/h (assistance limit for fast e-bikes), you'll barely notice the extra watts, and more grip on wet surface is a good safety argument.

One thing to note is that the extra weight of the bike is unsprung (apart from the cushioning of the tyres). This means it subjects the wheels and frame/fork to greater shock loads than the same weight on the rider. People are squishy and tend to do what's comfortable, such as unweighting the saddle over bumps, using the legs as shock absorbers. This is nicer for the bike as well as the rider.
A lot of e-bikes (concentrating on mass market hybrids and city bikes) have a little suspension on the fork, which mitigates this for heavy components except rear hub motors. They keep tend to attract riders who perhaps lack the experience to soften the bumps in the road, and may be using a big soft saddle that soaks up a bit of those bumps. The motor also means hitting those bumps harder - again greater peak shock.
E-bikes are also a good choice for carrying heavy loads, whether shopping or children, so the non-rider load  could well be higher on average.
All in all, that adds up to a few arguments for a tougher build, and the motor does a lot to deal with the downside of a heavy bike.

Its complex, if you consider 'standard' tire sizes of a couple of decades, or even a few years ago, compared to now probably balances the extra weight of EBikes as far as shock loads.  I suppose it boils down to there is no simple answer....

One more argument why mass is less important for eBikes: They are already too heavy to easily carry (e.g. up or down stairs). So adding a kg or two to make them much more sturdy and durable doesn’t really do any harm. One more argument for puncture proof tyres: With the high weight and motor, taking out the wheels is difficult so you want some reliable tyres.

@Michael I see people carrying folding e-bikes quite a bit (in work, but also because the lift is broken at the station) so it's not impossible. But harder than carrying my folding bike with a pannier full of shopping on it. My folder has hub gears and I used to look after a bike with a rear hub motor, so it's a similar hassle taking out the back wheel - and I've fitted tough tyres to that

E-bike oriented components usually fall into one of three categories:

Those that are specifically designed to better handle the specific mechanical properties of an e-bike, usually at the expense of weight (which is less of a critical consideration for an e-bike than a traditional bike). Items in this category are almost always beneficial irrespective of the usage of the e-bike, provided they match up with the type usage. These items are also usually explicitly rated for use with e-bikes.
Those that are specifically designed to accommodate the specific usage patterns of people who tend to use e-bikes, also often at the expense of weight. These may or may not be beneficial, with it really depending on the specific usage of the bike.
Those that are marketed specifically to e-bike users, but do not really fall specifically into the other two categories. These might be beneficial, but it’s less about the e-bike aspect and more about how you use your bike specifically.

E-bike drivetrains are solidly in the first category, and the same is true of the (good) e-bike wheels. E-bikes are heavier than regular bikes, so they benefit, sometimes significantly, from heavier spokes that better handle that extra weight.
E-bike tires are usually going to be in the second category. Most of them are just heavier tires designed for overall improved durability in the face of high torque and/or heavy loads, which works well for e-bikes because it reduces the replacement frequency for tires. Some of the better ones are also designed to better handle wet riding conditions (and are targeted mostly at commuters) or to provide better overall traction (and are more targeted at eMTB riders).
Forks I can’t really comment on, since I’ve not seen any specifically labelled as being ‘for e-bikes’. Heavy fork/frame construction could fall into the first category (especially for eMTB usage), and having some suspension in the fork could help with some usage types and thus fall into the second category.

For the forks, I’m aware of the Fox AWL, SR Suntour has an equivalent range. They are rated for higher weight (170kg) and have mounting points for fenders and ABS units. These are for touring bikes and light usage main bikes.

@Rеnаud Interesting, ABS units are not something I would have thought of in this case (but then, I live in the US and have only ever dealt with what the government here calls class 1 e-bikes, which are unlikely to need ABS), and would definitely qualify as beneficial.

ABS is mostly found on high-end trekking e-bikes for the front brakes (also the ones limited to 25kph). I don’t think it’s available for muscular bikes, but don’t know much more about the details.
